# how use a windows pc as bluetooth hid?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, hid, emulation

How can I turn my pc it into a bluetooth HID. I would like to send keys, like a bluetooth keyboard hid, to a mobile device using only a computer with bluetooth adapter.

Can I change my PC profile to a bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: I'd be really interested to know the answer to this, too.. I believe you'd have to have special bluetooth software on the PC for this, essentially modify your PC's bluetooth setup at the stack level (which is software in most PCs)

Comment: related thread: [Windows mobile device to emulate a Bluetooth HID device.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/281081/making-a-windows-mobile-device-emulate-a-bluetooth-hid-device)

Comment: Related thread, with better answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177186/is-it-possible-to-make-a-computer-behave-as-a-bluetooth-hid-device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached the answer for this question. In order to use your pc as bluetooth HID you must have a special hardware that can implement a HID profile. 
I did not found any device that could implement this. The only way is to build one with a specific hardware piece like RN-42 .
anyway, there is no way to do this via software with your default bluetooth hardware on your pc.

Comment: No, it's entirely a software issue, the bluez bluetooth stack on Linux has the ability to do it. AFAIK only very recent versions of Widcomm have the ability on windows and even then I haven't found out how to activate it.